# Error while trying to deploy Laravel to Cloud Foundry

Tags: php, laravel, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy a basic Laravel application to Cloud Foundry. Below you can see the output after I ran `ibmcloud cf push`:

```
Invoking 'cf push'...

Pushing from manifest to org ***** / space dev as *****...
Using manifest file *****\manifest.yml
Getting app info...
Updating app with these attributes...
  name:                *****
  path:                *****
  buildpacks:
    https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git#v4.4.13
  disk quota:          1G
  health check type:   port
  instances:           1
  memory:              256M
  stack:               cflinuxfs3
  services:
    Db2-8n
    availability-monitoring-auto
  env:
    APP_DEBUG
    APP_ENV
    APP_NAME
    CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT
    CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT
  routes:
    *****.mybluemix.net

Updating app *****...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 26.79 MiB / 26.79 MiB [===========] 100.00% 11s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 79671882-f747-4d8b-8466-68fb1c4bfc6a creating container for instance c10e2d4c-d35f-4920-8002-ce81e32dcc3c
   Cell 79671882-f747-4d8b-8466-68fb1c4bfc6a successfully created container for instance c10e2d4c-d35f-4920-8002-ce81e32dcc3c
   Downloading app package...
   Downloading build artifacts cache...
   Downloaded build artifacts cache (221B)
   Downloaded app package (43.9M)
   -------> Buildpack version 4.4.13
   Installing HTTPD
   HTTPD 2.4.43
   Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/httpd/httpd_2.4.43_linux_x64_cflinuxfs3_59c67ff8.tgz] to [/tmp]
   Installing PHP
   PHP 7.4.5
   Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/php/php7_7.4.5_linux_x64_cflinuxfs3_c0055c53.tgz] to [/tmp]
   The extension 'mcrypt' is not provided by this buildpack.
   Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/php/php7_7.4.5_linux_x64_cflinuxfs3_c0055c53.tgz] to [/tmp]
   Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/composer/composer_1.10.5_linux_noarch_any-stack_a1f79ebd.phar] to [/tmp]
     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
   100   482  100   482    0     0   2386      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2386
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Installing dependencies from lock file
   Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 37 removals
     - Removing webmozart/assert (1.9.1)
     - Removing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.0)
     - Removing sebastian/version (2.0.1)
     - Removing sebastian/type (1.1.3)
     - Removing sebastian/resource-operations (2.0.1)
     - Removing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0)
     - Removing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1)
     - Removing sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.3)
     - Removing sebastian/global-state (3.0.0)
     - Removing sebastian/exporter (3.1.2)
     - Removing sebastian/environment (4.2.3)
     - Removing sebastian/diff (3.0.2)
     - Removing sebastian/comparator (3.0.2)
     - Removing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1)
     - Removing scrivo/highlight.php (v9.18.1.1)
     - Removing phpunit/phpunit (8.5.8)
     - Removing phpunit/php-token-stream (3.1.1)
     - Removing phpunit/php-timer (2.1.2)
     - Removing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
     - Removing phpunit/php-file-iterator (2.0.2)
     - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (7.0.10)
     - Removing phpspec/prophecy (1.11.1)
     - Removing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.3.0)
     - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.2.0)
     - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0)
     - Removing phar-io/version (2.0.1)
     - Removing phar-io/manifest (1.0.3)
     - Removing nunomaduro/collision (v4.2.0)
     - Removing myclabs/deep-copy (1.10.1)
     - Removing mockery/mockery (1.4.1)
     - Removing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1)
     - Removing fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1)
     - Removing filp/whoops (2.7.3)
     - Removing facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.1)
     - Removing facade/ignition (2.3.4)
     - Removing facade/flare-client-php (1.3.4)
     - Removing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.1)
   Package moontoast/math is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use brick/math instead.
   Generating optimized autoload files

     [RuntimeException]
     Could not scan for classes inside "database/seeds" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

   install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
   -----> Composer command failed
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/scripts/compile.py", line 59, in <module>
       .from_build_pack('lib/additional_commands')
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 212, in extensions
       process_extension(path, ctx, 'compile', process, args=[self])
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 69, in process_extension
       success(getattr(extn, to_call)(*args))
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 444, in compile
       return composer.compile(install)
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/lib/extension_helpers.py", line 154, in compile
       self._compile(install)
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 196, in _compile
       self.run()
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 343, in run
       *self._ctx['COMPOSER_INSTALL_OPTIONS'])
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/extensions/composer/extension.py", line 390, in run
       shell=True)
     File "/tmp/buildpackdownloads/a299fb3027da6b25566e06badf712812/lib/build_pack_utils/runner.py", line 109, in stream_output
       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
   build_pack_utils.runner.CalledProcessError: Command '<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w' at 0x7f994f249930>' returned non-zero exit status 1
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1
   Exit status 223
   Cell 79671882-f747-4d8b-8466-68fb1c4bfc6a stopping instance c10e2d4c-d35f-4920-8002-ce81e32dcc3c
   Cell 79671882-f747-4d8b-8466-68fb1c4bfc6a destroying container for instance c10e2d4c-d35f-4920-8002-ce81e32dcc3c
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

The log of `ibmcloud cf push` with `BP_DEBUG` set to `true` is available here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NL1KxqdJv4k0QtIrrySwb-XF_7VwFO7l/view?usp=sharing

Here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.22.2",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my `options.json` file:

```
{
    "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_70_LATEST}",
    "COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR": "vendor",
    "WEBDIR": "public"
}
```

Here is my `manifest.yml` file:

```
---
 applications:
 - name: *****
   memory: 256M
   buildpacks: [ https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git#v4.4.13 ]
   random-route: true
   env:
     APP_DEBUG: false
     CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT: 15
     CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT: 15
     APP_NAME: *****
```

I've been searching for a solution to this issue for quite a while now, but I couldn't find anything that could help me. I hope someone here has better luck and can find a solution to this... Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Composer is running during staging. Composer is failing saying it can't find the folder `database/seeds`. Does that actually exist? Can you run `composer install` locally?

Comment: @DanielMikusa `database/seeds` exists and it contains the file `DatabaseSeeder.php`. `composer install` outputs `Nothing to install or update`.

Comment: OK, that's good. Can you `cf set-env <your-app> BP_DEBUG True` and repeat your `cf push`. That should give a lot more debug output from the buildpack. You may need to throw it in a gist, not sure if it will fit in the question. Link me to that and I'll see if I can spot what it's doing. Something is wrong with the relative path and it's not finding those files.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Updated! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would also like to point out that the deployment fails even when I remove this directory from the `composer.json` file.

Comment: Where is your `options.json` file located? I don't see it being loaded and it seems to be not picking up your WEBDIR setting. Also, this log doesn't have the same error. Let's try to focus on the error you listed in your question. When that gets resolved, if there's more problems we can move onto those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218932/discussion-between-rcralph-and-daniel-mikusa).

Comment: @DanielMikusa I moved our conversation into a chat so we could communicate in a better way, just to let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was renaming the `.pb-config` folder to `.bp-config`. The tutorial available under [this link](https://developer.ibm.com/depmodels/cloud/tutorials/build-and-deploy-a-laravel-php-app-using-cloud-foundry/) has a spelling error and that was the reason for all the suffering...